# Do I need to create a WCF service to read from a XML file?

Tags: wcf

I need to read from a XML file, get some data from the file and return the data.

Do I need to create a WCF service for that?

If so, do i need to host the service? Im not too sure how exactly WCF works, (though Ive been through quite a few tutorials) What exactly do I need to implement? I guess the IService interface, the actual Service implementation, what about the client, do I need to worry about the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need an [XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx)

OLD [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720458%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) of a XMLReader

About [WCF Services](http://www.wcftutorial.net/) - just FYI

Comment: thanks, so what would be the advantages of using WCF in this case?

Comment: WCF is like a webservice which can return XML.  Are you writing a SilverLight application which reads XML and sends it to your XAML / XAP?  If so, then you would need a WCF service.  But if you're just reading XML and doing something with the data, then you just need a reader.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, my Silverlight Application does read XML and sends it to XAML, so I guess I need a WCF service for it. Then should I use the Silverlight template, or the WCF template? Thanks

Comment: I would love to help you out.  Your question is really looking for a tutorial of how to bind and display data for Silverlight.  It is really simple once you're shown once but it's difficult to answer in a short answer here.  Feel free to send an email and I'll send you a sample solution or point you to one.  http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/ is a good place to look around.

Answer (score 2):

[WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) developed not for working with XML. You can use [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for work with XML documents. It can be simpler then using XMLReader but, you'll have problems if you want to work with really BIG XML documents.